# What is the best way to write common code and use it entire project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, design-patterns, singleton

I'm calling alerts, view's colours, spinners and components properties etc. from Shared class. Is it correct approach. if not what is the best way to write common code and use it entire project.

Ex: My shared class code is...

```
import UIKit

class SharedClass: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = SharedClass()

    var spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()

//Show activity indicator
func activityIndicator() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {//Conditionally unwrap it instead of force unwrap

  //                let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow! //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
            self.transparentView = UIView()
            self.transparentView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height)
            self.transparentView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
            window.addSubview(self.transparentView!)

            if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad {
                //                    self.spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge)
                self.spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge)
                self.spinner.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
            } else {
                //                    self.spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .white)
                self.spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .white)
                self.spinner.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
            }
            self.spinner.center = window.center
            self.transparentView?.addSubview(self.spinner)
            self.spinner.startAnimating()

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 40.0) {//Stop spinner after 40 Sec's
                self.stopActivityIndicator()
            }
        }
    }
}

//Stop activity indicator
func stopActivityIndicator() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.spinner.stopAnimating()
        self.spinner.removeFromSuperview()
        self.transparentView?.removeFromSuperview()//Some times getting error here
    }
}

 //Email validation
func isValidEmail(email: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    var valid = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: email)
    if valid {
        valid = !email.contains("Invalid email id")
    }
    return valid
}

//Mobile number validation
func isValidPhone(phone: String) -> Bool {
    let phoneRegex = "^((0091)|(\\+91)|0?)[6789]{1}\\d{9}$"; // @"^((0091)|(\\+91)|0?)[6789]{1}\\d{9}$"        "^[0-9]{6,14}$"
    let valid = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex).evaluate(with: phone)
    return valid
}

 private override init() {

}

}

//Alert function
extension UIViewController {
    func showAlert(title: String, msg: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

//Set TF shadow in login VC
extension UITextField {
    func TFProperties() {
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 199/255, green: 217/255, blue: 223/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        layer.shadowRadius = 5
        layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 199/255, green: 217/255, blue: 223/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.cornerRadius = 4
    }
}

//Set View shadow in OTPVerify VC
extension UIView {
func subViewShadow() {
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    layer.shadowRadius = 3
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = 1
    layer.cornerRadius = 4
}
func viewShadow() {
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    layer.shadowRadius = 3
}
func collectionViewCellBorder() {
    layer.cornerRadius = 5
    layer.borderColor = UIColor UIColor.gray.cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = 1.0
}
}
```

Comment: write extensions to classes that should use this content, in example for alert it should be `UIViewController`

Comment: Already I'm using  extensions , but I don't know what is the best approach.  //Alert function
extension UIViewController {
    func showAlert(title: String, msg: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

Comment: yes you have extensions and what else would you want to do?

Comment: @ Lu_, I'm using this function from shared class func isValidEmail(email: String) -> Bool { } is it ok or not. And I'm using spinner also...

Answer (score 3):

Create a Common framework:

- XCode>File>New>Project>

[image: Project Selection]

- Cocoa Touch Framework>

[image: Cocoa Touch Framework]

- Set name of your framework (Common etc.)>

[image: Common Framework]

- Select your main **workspace** on 'Add to' & 'Group' section and create>

[image: Create Framework]

- You should link your framework to main target linked libraries>

[image: Link Binary with Libraries]

- You can create classes in your framework>

[image: Colors in framework]

- And use main project, just import this framework like 'import Common'.

[image: Usage]

**Note:** You should use access level modifiers on Common framework (private, public, open etc.).

*Access Level Modifiers:*

**Source:** 
[Abhimuralidharan's Swift 4— Access Control Article](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/swift-3-0-1-access-control-9e71d641a56c)

1. Public:
    Enable an entity to be used outside the defining module (target).
2. Private:
    Private access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration, and to extensions of that declaration that are in the same file.

Comment: @ Emre Ciftci, very nice answer... Today I learned one new point from your answer...

Comment: Hi @iOS. I'm very thankful for your comment. If you accepted please mark as accepted. Enjoy.

Comment: @ Emre Ciftci, can you  please explain wha twill happens if we use private or open in above function **myAppColor**. can we access our entire project.

Comment: Hello again @iOS. Please check my edit. myAppColor just a example. If you use 'private' you can not use this property in other module. If you use 'open' you can use this property in other module and you can override it. If you use 'public' you can use this property other module but can not override it.

Comment: @ Emre Ciftci, very nice... one more dought is is it mandatory to use access level modifiers for functions or variables.

Comment: If functions or variables are in a different module and are to be used externally (public) or not (private), it is necessary to use them. By the way if you do not use any access level modifiers, swift set 'internal' modifier to your variable / function / class / struct / enum etc.

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is right know is a singleton pattern. For managers like alertViewController, picker control, like login-logout etc that's a good to use. It could be called and used several different views. It reduces code duplications as well. For example, you need to use action sheet for two different view controller. At this point you can use singleton pattern and give some parameters from outside this shared instance's methods and call it for your specific operations from one point. You would not need to create two different alert controller in every each of your controller :). Use it wisely :).

Comment: @ erkutbas, may I know what is  login-logout

Comment: For example you have an application getting user authentication. Login, Register views background operations such as user login, user logout, user register, forget password operations can be handled in one singleton class for all over the application hierarchy. Because in those cases user login app from view A, but logout from B. That's why a singleton pattern helps developer to manage all backend work at one place.

Answer (score 1):

This is a correct approach if you can also use `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` for your view related work like add shadow, corner radius, etc so that you can change it from your storyboard also. 
Like.

```
@IBDesignable extension UIView{

    @IBInspectable
    public var viewCornerRadius: CGFloat{
        set{
            self.layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }get{
            return self.layer.cornerRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            let color = UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
            return color
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var shadowOpacity: Float {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowOffset: CGSize {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOffset
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = newValue
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let color = layer.shadowColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let color = newValue {
                layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
            } else {
                layer.shadowColor = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Amit gupta, thank you very much. But it's looking very difficult , because of it's first I'm seeing this code.

Comment: it's not working.. i added a swift file in my project. then copy and past your code then change it from stroyboard.. but outbut not display on live. when i run project it's working fine